# Alignment of paragraphs and headings in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a design below which I am trying to replicate in HTML and CSS:

[image]

Note: I have written text `Margin` and `Padding` to make things easy to understand. It will not come in the actual design

At this moment, I am able to get this in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hjudjvo/1/show/).

The only thing which is not matching the above design in the fiddle `are the paragraphs (eg: Our main goal, Among our biggest, etc) in every box which don't have line break`. I am considering boxes as every job-opening with titles (Back-end .., Front-end .., etc) and paragraphs (eg: Our main goal, Among our biggest, etc).

The CSS for every box is:

```
.firstrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}


.firstrow #front-end {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a improved version of your code, just using flexbox, without using `float`s or anything else.

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  color: #444444;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5%;
}

.row>div {
  padding: 5%;
  background: gray;
  margin: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="job-openings">
  <h2>Seems Interesting? Apply Now</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="back-end">
      <h3>Back-end Developer</h3>
      <p> Our main goal is to build and maintain the online platform and...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="front-end">
      <h3>Front-end Web Developer</h3>
      <p>Among our biggest priorities are interface design and user experience...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="graphics">
      <h3>Graphics Designer</h3>
      <p> We believe in the power of design. Our designers are motivated, creative and...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sales">
      <h3>Sales &amp; Marketing</h3>
      <p>Our Marketing team is focussed on driving growth and building a brand that customers love...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Op's Comment to answer:

> Back-end and front-end will come in one row with graphics designer and
>   sales and marketing in another row.

Assuming you want to have always 2 rows, then you can use `flex:0 50%` instead of `flex:1`, in this case `flex: 0 calc(50% - 30px)` to take in count the margin

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  color: #444444;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5%;
}

.row>div {
  padding: 5%;
  background: gray;
  margin: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 calc(50% - 30px);
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="job-openings">
  <h2>Seems Interesting? Apply Now</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="back-end">
      <h3>Back-end Developer</h3>
      <p> Our main goal is to build and maintain the online platform and...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="front-end">
      <h3>Front-end Web Developer</h3>
      <p>Among our biggest priorities are interface design and user experience...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="graphics">
      <h3>Graphics Designer</h3>
      <p> We believe in the power of design. Our designers are motivated, creative and...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sales">
      <h3>Sales &amp; Marketing</h3>
      <p>Our Marketing team is focussed on driving growth and building a brand that customers love...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Back-end and front-end will come in one row with graphics designer and sales and marketing in another row.

Comment: It worked. One quick question. Also, I can see there is an overflow in the x-axis. Is there any way we can avoid without using overflow-x: hidden ?

Comment: I don't see that https://i.imgur.com/uqAj0ZW.png. you might want to remove the default `margin` from `h3` and `p`